# Blazor UI not being updated after onOnAfterRenderAsync

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side page that needs to load data when the user goes to the page.  However, after `OnAfterRenderAsync` executes it does not update the UI.  The data is loaded correctly and if I create a "refresh" button to flag the page it works.

I have something like:

```
@page "/mypage

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Temp">Refresh</button>

@if (_loading)
{
    <p>
        <em>Loading...</em>
    </p>
}
else
{
    <p>
        <em>Here is your data</em>
    </p>
}

@code {
    private bool _loading { get; set; }
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _loading = true;

    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!firstRender) return;
        //Amazong loading code
        _loading = false;
    }

    private void Temp()
    {
        _loading = false;
    }

}
```

Stepping through the `OnAfterRenderAsync` does show that `_loading` is correctly set to false.  Stepping through `Temp()` does show that `_loading` is set to false.

I am guessing that `OnAfterRenderAsync` is not updating the DOM, the fact clicking the button forces an update to the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should load your data in the OnInitialized(Async) pair.
If you place code in the OnAfterRender(Async) pair, which change the state of your component, such as: `_loading = false;`, you should manually call the StateHasChanged method, which notify the component that its state has changed, and that it should re-render.

```
and if I create a "refresh" button to flag the page it works.
```

It re-render not because you "flag the page"... In Blazor, UI events, such as the click event automatically calls the StateHasChanged method. When Blazor was at its first phases of development, we had to call the StateHasChanged method manually.

Comment: But it act stupid, I have a third party provider redirect me into this page, and `OnInitialized` get called twice, on first call it consume the code third party assinged me, and on second it cause error, and blazor crash

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to use OnInitialized event.

For example if you are loading a list of categories you could apply the following test conditions in the razor markup:

```
@if (categories == null && _loadFailed)
{
    <h1 class="text-danger">The data has failed to load please try again in a little bit..</h1>
}
else if (categories == null)
{
    <h1 class="text-success">Loading...</h1>
    <div style="display:normal;margin:auto" class="loader"></div>
}
else if (categories.Count == 0)
{
    <text>No categories found</text>
}
else...
```

Comment: The problem that I have is that putting the load in OnInitialized, caused the page not to load